# Compare Lines on csv file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

I have this csv file which has an answer key in the top row and all of the students answers below it in a roll like so:

```
First Name,Last Name,Student ID,Version,Score,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Answer Key,,,p,75,j,c,g,c,g,d,f,a,j,c
Mark,Mueller,14697,p,35,j,c,f,c,d,f,a,j,c,j
Andruw ,Wittles,15674,p,75,a,c,d,f,h,g,a,d,j,d
Bob,Johnson,32423,p,36,d,a,j,i,d,a,b,c,j,d
John,Smith,12343,p,67,a,c,b,g,h,j,a,d,c,b
```

The problem is that I cant find a good way to compare the answer key and the students answers. If you could help me also give the student's id the score. (The 5 digit number after the name)

Thanks.

Comment: Create a class for the students, load the answers into an array and compare that array with an answers key array. Each student has its own instance so all the data is properly associated and you can iterate through all your students for whatever purpose you need

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If
you [edit] your question to describe what you have tried so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: There are plenty of csv parsers out there like [this CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). No need to reinvent the wheel when solving generic problems unless this is for school and your teacher is mandating you write your own code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer that hopefully demonstrates the beauty of OO:

```
public class TestAnswers
{
    public string FirstName, LastName, Version;
    public int StudentId, Score;
    public string[] Answers;

    public TestAnswers(string testAnswersString)
    {
        string[] elements = testAnswersString.Split(',');
        FirstName = elements[0];
        LastName = elements[1];
        int.TryParse(elements[2], out StudentId);
        Version = elements[3];
        int.TryParse(elements[4], out Score);
        Answers = elements.Skip(5).Take(elements.Length - 5).ToArray();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    const string AnswerKeyName = "Answer Key";
    public TestAnswers AnswerKey;
    public TestAnswers[] StudentAnswers;

    public Test(string testCsvPath)
    {
        var allTestAnswers = File.ReadAllLines(testCsvPath).Skip(1).Select(answers => new TestAnswers(answers));
        AnswerKey = allTestAnswers.Single(answers => answers.FirstName == AnswerKeyName);
        StudentAnswers = allTestAnswers.Where(answers => answers.FirstName != AnswerKeyName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

By breaking the problem down and creating an object that can worry about one persons answers and then another object that worries about collating all those answers into a test, it becomes much more manageable. You can then query the collection of Student answers against the Answer Key in the Test object to work out whatever you need.

Comment: @Neolisk Though the idea is nice, no need to be nice about it, in your words "*Splitting strings by comma to parse CSV? Seriously?*"

Comment: @Neolisk What you're missing is that this answer is essentially the same as mine, it is even very specific to the question an unlikely to help others, after all, StackOverflow *is* indexed from search engines

Comment: @Neolisk I can make it much more specific if you'd prefer so your points comes across better?

Comment: Please try and keep the comments relevant to the answer otherwise I'll simply delete it, thanks. I tailored the example to be as simple and concise as possible as I felt that was most helpful to the OP.

Comment: @TVOHM: I withdrew my comments from your answer. You can wait for Alfie to do the same, or flag for moderator's attention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate through each line of the csv and compare the values to the first line. notice how the **first loop starts with** `i = 1` **to avoid checking if the first line equals itself**. The rest has also been adjusted to avoid the first 3 columns which are First name, Last name and Student.

```
string[] allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(theCSV);
for (i = 1; i < allText.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    string[] lineText = allText[i].Split(",");
    bool[] trueOrFalse = new bool[lineText.GetLength(0) - 3];
    for (i2 = 3; i2 < lineText.GetLength(0); i2++)
    {
        trueOrFalse[i2] = lineText[i2] == allText[0].Split(",")[i2] ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Splitting strings by comma to parse CSV? Seriously?

Comment: I don't see the issue with that, it works does it not?

Comment: It **only** works if you are very lucky with the CSV file. If you happen to get commas or newlines inside values, your code becomes useless. There are high quality, high performance CSV parsers out there for a reason. Example: https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv

Comment: I wrote this code specifically for this problem, I don't feel as if these people will have commas in their names or in the *choice* answer formats, therefore I feel this is viable

Comment: The question specifically states "CSV" file. A viable solution to parse a CSV file is one that is standards compliant. StackOverflow is indexed from search engines, *people come here to find the right answer*.

Comment: And as such, this answer is correct, sure it could be put into a class, but it still does what is needed

Comment: If you want to succeed on StackOverflow, you should listen to more senior members.

Comment: If you want people to want to succeed on StackOverflow, you should give criticism without being too harsh, and not try to use your seniority to suggest you are a higher being than newer users

Comment: If I didn't want people to succeed, I would let both of these answers rot with no upvotes, as the question is likely to be closed anyway. What I am doing right now is not rewarded by reputation or any other means.

Comment: There is a difference between "letting answers rot with no upvotes", even though I am pretty sure you downvoted me, and outright lowering their chance of posting another answer because they are deterred by nonsense like this. If anything you're causing me to have less success by saying all this than you are by leaving the post alone

Comment: Unfortunately, 1 out of 100 people reacts like you did. Others fix the answer and get upvotes. I did not downvote you, and no-one did.

Comment: Then likely 1 out of 100 people is going to give up on the site thanks to you, so that's not a great track record. Luckily I am happy to move on and answer more questions because believe it or not I DO want to help and I AM trying, I answered and sure, my answer wasn't the best but your comment was needlessly harsh, something I would have though a *more senior* member would know about

Comment: Well, you cannot possibly write the best answer, if you don't consider feedback from other members. If this feedback sounds negative/harsh to you, it does not make less of a feedback. For example, getting low marks at school, doesn't mean everyone hates you. It only means two things 1) you are not as good as you think 2) someone cares to help you become better. Now, if you choose to specifically ignore my feedback, I'm totally fine with that, you'll meet other members, and hopefully one day realize the truth. Experience takes time.